# sum without grouping and max number of duplicate value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table something like this

```
SELECT '123' AS Dept, '999' AS Sub, 1.789 'Stdhrs', 56 'Dollars' UNION ALL
SELECT '123' AS Dept, '999' AS Sub, 1.489 'Stdhrs', 66 'Dollars' UNION ALL
SELECT '123' AS Dept, '999' AS Sub, 1.789 'Stdhrs', 11 'Dollars' UNION ALL
SELECT '123' AS Dept, '999' AS Sub, 1.789 'Stdhrs', 10 'Dollars' UNION ALL

SELECT '123' AS Dept, '991' AS Sub, 2.679 'Stdhrs', 12 'Dollars' UNION ALL
SELECT '123' AS Dept, '991' AS Sub, 2.679 'Stdhrs', 10 'Dollars' UNION ALL
SELECT '123' AS Dept, '991' AS Sub, 2.679 'Stdhrs', 11 'Dollars' UNION ALL
SELECT '123' AS Dept, '991' AS Sub, 2.679 'Stdhrs', 12 'Dollars' UNION ALL
SELECT '123' AS Dept, '991' AS Sub, 2.699 'Stdhrs', 12 'Dollars' UNION ALL

SELECT '124' AS Dept, '991' AS Sub, 1.111 'Stdhrs', 10 'Dollars' UNION ALL
SELECT '124' AS Dept, '991' AS Sub, 1.111 'Stdhrs', 13 'Dollars' UNION ALL
SELECT '124' AS Dept, '991' AS Sub, 1.112 'Stdhrs', 10 'Dollars' UNION ALL
SELECT '124' AS Dept, '991' AS Sub, 1.112 'Stdhrs', 8  'Dollars' UNION ALL
SELECT '124' AS Dept, '991' AS Sub, 1.112 'Stdhrs', 14 'Dollars' UNION ALL
SELECT '124' AS Dept, '991' AS Sub, 1.112 'Stdhrs', 16 'Dollars' UNION ALL

SELECT '128' AS Dept, '111' AS Sub, 4.112 'Stdhrs', 10 'Dollars' UNION ALL

SELECT '132' AS Dept, '777' AS Sub, 5.555 'Stdhrs', 11 'Dollars' UNION ALL
SELECT '132' AS Dept, '777' AS Sub, 1.222 'Stdhrs', 10 'Dollars'
```

I would like to see the results

```
SELECT '123' AS Dept, '999' AS Sub, 1.789 'Stdhrs', 143 'Dollars' UNION ALL
SELECT '123' AS Dept, '991' AS Sub, 2.679 'Stdhrs', 57  'Dollars' UNION ALL
SELECT '124' AS Dept, '991' AS Sub, 1.112 'Stdhrs', 71  'Dollars' UNION ALL
SELECT '128' AS Dept, '111' AS Sub, 4.112 'Stdhrs', 10  'Dollars' UNION ALL
SELECT '132' AS Dept, '777' AS Sub, 5.555 'Stdhrs', 21  'Dollars' UNION ALL
```

Basically the Stdhrs shouldn't roll up and only displays the number which have the max duplicates. but it should rollup the dollars field.

Thanks,

Comment: What do you do in the case of ties for number of `Stdhrs`?

Comment: Get the max of (Stdhrs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took two CTEs, but this was the first thing that popped into my head.

```
;WITH CTE_CountsAndTotals AS
(
    SELECT
        Dept,
        Sub,
        Stdhrs,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Dept, Sub, Stdhrs) AS cnt,
        SUM(Dollars) OVER (PARTITION BY Dept, Sub) AS Dollars
    FROM
        dbo.Test
),
CTE_MostFrequentStdhrs AS
(
    SELECT
        Dept,
        Sub,
        Stdhrs,
        Dollars,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Dept, Sub ORDER BY cnt DESC, Stdhrs DESC) AS row_num
    FROM
        CTE_CountsAndTotals
)
SELECT
    Dept,
    Sub,
    Stdhrs,
    Dollars
FROM
    CTE_MostFrequentStdhrs
WHERE
    row_num = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit complicated, and can probably be simplified, but you can do this by getting the `COUNT` of the `Stdhrs`, then ranking them via `DENSE_RANK()`, and pulling out the `MAX()` Stdhrs from it where it has the highest `COUNT` (e.g.: `DENSE_RANK() = 1`).

```
;With Cte As
(
    Select  T.*, Dense_Rank() Over (Partition by T.Dept, T.Sub Order By X.Count Desc) Dense_Rank
    From    TestTable   T
    Join
    (
        Select  Dept, Sub, Stdhrs, Count(*) Count
        From    TestTable
        Group By Dept, Sub, Stdhrs
    ) X On  X.Dept = T.Dept
        And X.Sub = T.Sub
        And X.Stdhrs = T.Stdhrs
)
Select  C.Dept, C.Sub, X.FreqStdHrs As Stdhrs, Sum(C.Dollars) As Dollars
From    Cte C
Cross Apply
(
    Select  Max(Stdhrs) As FreqStdHrs
    From    Cte C2
    Where   C2.Dept = C.Dept
    And     C2.Sub = C.Sub
    And     C2.Dense_Rank = 1
) X
Group By C.Dept, C.Sub, X.FreqStdHrs
```

[<kbd>**SQL Fiddle Live Demo**</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b2529/5/0)

Comment: There's no need for the `DISTINCT` with the `OVER` clauses. This is equivalent to a simple `GROUP BY`. Also, the OP wants the most frequent `Stdhrs`. `MAX` is just as a tie-breaker.

Comment: @TomH True, but the OP specified in the title they did not want to use `GROUP BY`

Comment: @Siyual If you see for the Dept 123 and Sub 991 in that case stdhrs should be 2.679 and not 2.699

Comment: I'm sorry about the title...can use group by

Comment: Updated query per requirement.